# Common Lisp: getting the Unicode name of a character

Tags: unicode, common-lisp

In CL, can I get the Unicode name of a character into a string?  Is there a
function that, receiving `#\α` as an argument, would return `"GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA"`?

Comment: Start with [`char-code` and `code-char`](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/strings.html#chars).

Comment: See also [`CHAR-NAME`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_char_n.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [cl-unicode](https://common-lisp.net/~loliveira/ediware/cl-unicode/doc/) library:

```
CL-USER> (cl-unicode:unicode-name #\α)
"GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA"
CL-USER> (cl-unicode:unicode-name 945)
"GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA"
```

Comment: I'm new to this, is there a package manager I can use to get this library?  (Using sbcl and slime.)

Comment: Yes, it's called quicklisp. You install it as detailed here: https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/
Then you can write (ql:quickload "cl-unicode") to fetch and load the library and its dependencies. You can browse available libraries at http://quickdocs.org/

When you create a library of your own, you list its dependencies in its asd file. If you save the library in ~/quicklisp/ (or symlink it there), it will be quickloadable with dependencies as well.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `CHAR-NAME` is not standardized, but often you'll get:

```
? (char-name #\α)
"Greek_Small_Letter_Alpha"
```

In LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 40 > (char-name #\α)
"U+03B1"

CL-USER 41 > (system::lookup-unicode-character-name #\α)
"GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA"
```